# The specified protocol identifier is not known to the router Windows server 2022

Tags: vpn, l2tp, windows-server-2022

Im trying to configure L2TP vpn on windows server 2022.

Everything goes well except when client trying to connect it shows this error :

[image]

Things ive done :

1- The l2tp preshared key are same.(server/client)
2- firewall and antivirus are both disable during test.
3- Both Server and client authentication or set on EAP-MSCHAP v2

Server :

[image]

Client :

[image]

Also if i change the Authentication method on client i can see the error of connectivity on Server event viewer like this :

[image]

But if i use correct method it stuck on above error without any event log.

One more thing that i should mention , the checking of username and password will happen before i see the error.
because if i type wrong password, it will ask me to type the correct one. so error happen exactly after login and after i see this message :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [one thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcc48d6d-fa64-41ca-af8b-55dd04a872f4/peapeap-authentication?forum=winserverNIS) and [one article](https://www.configjon.com/always-on-vpn-troubleshooting/) online regarding this error message - both suggest the issue is IPv6 being disabled on the VPN server - have you checked for that? It seems like that prevents the RAS service from working even when you're only using IPv4.

Summarising the basic troubleshooting steps from the article linked above:

- Ensure IPv6 isn't disabled by a Group Policy
- Check for the `DisabledComponents` registry key in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters`. If present, it must be set to either `0` (IPv6 enabled) or `32` (IPv4 preferred).

For more information, do check the two links.